# The unicode fonts layout provided by Ubuntu vs. the official font layout

Tags: fonts, keyboard-layout, internationalization, unicode

While choosing Nepali language. I see there are slight differences between the layout provided by Ubuntu's Keyboard Layout vs. the standard font layout provided for Nepali language.

I am also not able to install the provided font. Is there a way to correct this ?

I get the Font from

http://mpp.org.np/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_details&gid=8&Itemid=63

and the layout is [image]

and the Ubuntu's layout is : [image]

There are no symbols - !@#$%^&*() .

Comment: Do you suggest fixing the Ubuntu 'standard', or are you looking for how to adjust the keyboard layout (for your needs)?

Comment: I would suggest to fix the Ubuntu's layout. It will be helpful for others as well. For the time being, I would like to see a way to adjust it myself.

Comment: Importantly, the `Zero Width Non Joiner` (plus key) and the `Zero Width Joiner` (equals key) is not functioning as it should. It is required to generate other important characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with Nepali romanized keyboard shipped with certain version of Ubuntu. correct version [here](http://www.nepalinux.org/input/ne)

> The Nepali Romanized Keyboard layout shipped with Ubuntu (located at
>   /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/np) is incomplete. The definition for the
>   whole upper row (1-0 keys) are missing. Also, more importantly,
>   zero-width joiner (ZWJ) and zero-width non-joiner (ZWNJ) characters
>   are wrongly defined

Jwalanta tackles this problem in detail in his [blog](http://jwalanta.blogspot.com/2009/04/fixing-nepali-unicode-in-ubuntu.html)

there is [keyboard layout editor](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor) if you want to create a new layout yourself This has some issues in 12.04 but there are workarounds

**edit**:

I got tired with issues in standard layout so built these based on iBus

- [one similar to Preeti and other ttf fonts](http://nepalitankan.blogspot.com/2013/10/nepali-traditional.html)
- [transliteration based](http://nepalitankan.blogspot.com/2013/11/ne-rom-translit.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.